# django about permission with email as username login

Tags: python, django, email

With django 1.7, I want to change useranme to email as login, I find django gives a official solution on their webpage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/ , but at the end of page, it says:

```
admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

What if I still need the permission to control different users in different group, if it will be a problem to use django's solution, or I should try other way

Comment: I think you can just add `PermissionsMixin` to the custom user class  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `AbstractUser` subclasses the `AbstractBaseUser` and the `PermissionsMixin` which should allow a user to have groups.

The examples in the link you posted only subclass `AbstractBaseUser`

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L374

I implemented a custom user (that uses email as username) for the first time a couple months ago (on django 1.6) and found myself having to refer to the source as much as the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, simply adding `PermissionsMixin` (found in the `django.contrib.auth.models` class) will allow you to assign and manage permissions.

I've also implemented a custom user that uses the email as a username, and utilizes `PermissionsMixin` - feel free to give it a look. I created it with the help of a combination of the Django docs and another Google'd tutorial - but I can't find the link.

https://github.com/ethanperez/t4k-rms/blob/master/riders/models.py